# Iframe content loading and onload event

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, onload

Having following code

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="..."></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById('myframe').onload = function() {
  alert('myframe is loaded');
};
</script>
```

Am I right that the `iframe` content is loaded by an extra thread so there may be a race condition? Is it possible that the `iframe` content will be loaded before the event handler in the script (running in the main thread) causing the `alert` to newer show?

Comment: No, you are not right. Why would you think it works this way? Did you research it? You get one thread of execution for JS in `top`. Load event for parent page fires after the `iframe` is loaded (and other stuff like linked JS files, CSS, images).  See JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/66xe7j1z/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exactly when does an IFRAME onload event fire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815263/exactly-when-does-an-iframe-onload-event-fire)

Comment: So is it guaranteed that the script is always executed before iframe load event occurs?

Comment: The way it is written yes. If the script is triggered later (such as in the top document's load event, which waits for all other loads to finish) then it will not. But the fact that you are asking question makes me wonder why.. did you run into this, and is your example posted here actually representative of the problem you were working on?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I don't have any problem with it just wanted to know how does it work. Unfortunately I still have some doubts. Doesn't the iframe content loaded in separate thread?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary Can You answer my last question?

Answer (score -1):

```js
  
  function iframeDidLoad(){
       alert("Hello World");
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="myiframe" src="#" onLoad="iframeDidLoad();"></iframe>
```